# Brand new lamp has me stumped

Tags: electrical

I bought a very expensive lamp with a 3-way switch.  I noticed when I got home that it has a red sticker stating 60 watt maximum.   The lowest A1 bulb I could find in 3 way was 30-70-100.  Are there other bulbs that can give me a safe 3-way choice and still be under the 60 watt limit??? I'm stumped.

Answer (score 3):

**A1** doesn't make any sense. But in general there are 3-way LED bulbs to fit any size and they don't use much power. For example, [this Cree 40W/50W/100W equivalent LED bulb](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Cree-40W-60W-100W-Equivalent-Soft-White-2700K-A21-3-Way-Exceptional-Light-Quality-LED-Light-Bulb-TA21-15027MDFH25-12WE26-1-11/304006415?irgwc=1&cm_mmc=afl-ir-27795-456723-&clickid=y7Ow8bQHsxyJRi-wUx0Mo382UklXt2zBIxb21M0):

[image]

fits an E26 socket and actual power used is 5W/9W/17W.

**Equivalent** power is often listed first. I think that is partially inertia/backwards compatibility - if you used to have a 30/70/100 bulb then that's what you will look for in a replacement, since bulbs have (generally) only recently been listed by the light they produce - lumens - instead of the power they use - watts. I think it is also partly "marketing" - people like to get more for their money, and 30/70/100 sounds like a lot more than 5/9/17, even though what you are *really* trying to get for your money is light, not power usage (which you actually want to minimize).

Answer (score 2):

The weird "60 Watt" thing flows from an *Underwriter's Laboratories* requirement for certifying lamps as safe.  This is necessary for a UL listing, which is necessary to sell it in the United States if your name isn't Amazon, eBay or AliSomething.

This limit refers to the **actual** thermal (heat) emissions of the bulb.  In old incandescent bulbs, 98% of the bulb's energy was spent making heat, not light... So when the lamp talks about 60 watt limit, they mean 60 watts worth of *heat*. Even the modern LEDs are only 10-12% efficient, so *as a rule of thumb*, a 17 watt LED is making 17 watts of heat.

Making a lamp that supports >60W of heat requires more expensive and extreme design, including style compromises. The reason they give you 3-way control on a 60-watt-limit is they figure you don't buy an expensive lamp and then put dollar store bulbs in it.  In other words **they expect you to use modern LED lights**.